# What is the unit of measurement used for fonts in Adobe Livecycle Workbench ES3?

Tags: fonts, adobe, font-size, livecycle

I have a question that could appears trivial, but I was not able to find an answer that would satisfy me. In what units of measurement are expressed font sizes that can be specified on a form in Adobe LiveCycle Workbench ES3? I don't know whether they're px, pt, mm, inch, ...

For Example, if I set Font=Arial and Size=9, this means that the size is 9 px/pt/mm/inch?

Is there a way to set the unit of measure that should be used for fonts?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [introduction](http://helpx.adobe.com/livecycle/help/mobile-forms/introduction.html) says that you're dealing with html5 and css.

So you can use [%, in, cm, mm, em, ex, pt, pc and px](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp). It is recommended to use the relative sizes: em and %.

I guess you are dealing with a graphical user interface. If it doesn't accept units of measurement, than just create a test and open the css file in a text editor to see what units are used.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I was using a graphical interface, but opening in a text editor my file, I found that the size units are pt.

Comment: To be clear: The recommended relative units (em and %) are recommended for output to browsers. If you output pdf's (representation of print) px makes sense because you're dealing with an exact canvas (A4, US Letter etc). Maybe the LiveCycle developers choose the most restrictive environment to be leading.